# SSIS Foreach Loop Not archiving files

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis, etl

I am having some problems with a foreach loop container within SSIS.

**This is the current setup:**

1. SQL Task to get parameters from a SQL table.
2. Foreach loop container
3. Script task within Foreach loop container which uses C# to archive files into folders which are specified within the parameters sourced from the SQL task to begin with.

**The problem:**

We load data from multiple folders for certain dataflows. In this scenario, only the first row parameter returned from the SQL task is being used. After that particular file has been archived off, I want the foreach loop to then proceed into the next folder, archive, then onto the next, archive etc until it is complete.

I have setup the Foreach File Enumerator how I thought was correct:
Collection > Expressions > Directory - This is set by a variable which is collected from the SQL task.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am having a bit of trouble proceeding with this right now.

Cheers.

Comment: Questions about code that show no code are decidedly difficult to debug. That said, any reason you chose to use a Script Task to perform the same task that a File System Task provides using out of the box functionality?

Comment: Make sure the `ResultSet` property of your SQL Task is set to 'Full result set' and not 'Single row'.